# How to float boxs using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am creating a responsive grid layout but want to know how to float boxes and keep the last container floated right with no margin.

For example. 
Full width desktop version will show 4 boxes.

Ipad will show 3 boxes

Phone will show 2 boxes. The last box will need to have 0 margin right.

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SGy4R/2/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box">the last box needs no margin right when full width and responsive</div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box">the last box needs no margin right when full width and responsive</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you set `width:480px;` and **needs no margin right when full width and responsive?!**

Comment: How would i set  the last with no margin, as when the site is full width it will have 4 boxes. smaller size it will have 3 boxes, mobile will have 2 boxes

Comment: you can use the [nth-of-type selector](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-of-type)  with media queries for different screen widths .  Eg: http://jsfiddle.net/SGy4R/3/

Comment: Thank you, I think the nth term is what I am looking for. to show only 3 or 2 boxes will i display the code like ? .box:nth-of-type(3n){margin-right:0}  .box:nth-of-type(2n){margin-right:0} ????

Comment: something like that - I have added a few media queries here:  http://jsfiddle.net/SGy4R/5/ but you will need to calculate the widths correctly for your needs

Comment: @PaulDesigner I think my answer is in the same veins as Pete, but with cross browser support.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
.box:nth-of-type(4n){
margin-right:0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your markup like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box">the last box needs no margin right when full width and responsive</div>
</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box">the last box needs no margin right when full width and responsive</div>
</div>
```

And set `margin-right: 0;` for last-child

```
.container > div:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: OP wants it responsive, so how do you propose to target 3n and 2n?

Answer (score 1):

I actually think this topic is a bit more tricky as I am sure that you do not only want to remove the margin on the last box but you also want all boxes to have the same width.

It means that we need to know how many boxes are currently displayed and disregard the ones hidden by the media query, remove the padding (I worked with paddings on a wrapper rather than margins) on the last container and share the padding among all boxes to make them equal in width.

**Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SGy4R/8/**

I basically get the width of the #container and count all **visible** children inside the container. I then get the padding of the first box to calculate the padding share for each box. With the for loop I apply the calculated width to each box element while removing the padding from the last one.

I added a media query to the fiddle so you can see how it works when there are 3 or 4 boxes inside the #container. Just resize the result pane and run the fiddle again.

```
// Get width of container
var cont_width = $('#container').width();
// Count box divs in container
var cont_children = $("#container > *:visible").length;
// Get box padding from first child
var box_padding = $('.box:first-child').innerWidth();
// Share last "non-existent" padding with all 4 boxes
var padding_share = box_padding / cont_children;
// Calculate box size
var box_width = (cont_width / cont_children) + padding_share;

// Set width for each box, remove padding for last box
for ( var i = 0; i <= cont_children; i++ ) {
    if (i === cont_children) {  
        $(".box:nth-child(" + i + ")").css({
            'width':box_width - box_padding,
            'padding-right': '0px'
        });
    }
    else {
        $(".box:nth-child(" + i + ")").width(box_width-box_padding);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help! will this work in all browsers and will boxes adjust when you physically change the browser size ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a media query:

```
// Normal
.box:nth-child(4n) { margin-right:0; }

@media (max-width: 3boxThreshold) {
    .box:nth-child(3n) { margin-right:0; }
}

@media (max-width: 2boxThreshold) {
    .box:nth-child(2n) { margin-right:0; }
}
```

However, the `n-th` child selector isn't a valid selector for older browsers so you would need to add some jQuery instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    removeMargin();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        removeMargin();
    });

    function removeMargin() {
        var wW = $(window).width();

        // Resets the boxes
        $('.box').css("margin-right", "insertDefaultValueHere");

        if (wW < 3boxThreshold)
            $('.box:nth-child(3n)').css("margin-right", 0);
        else if (wW < 2boxThreshold)
            $('.box:nth-child(2n)').css("margin-right", 0);
        else
            $('.box:nth-child(3n)').css("margin-right", 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle please?

Comment: @PaulDesigner Are you unable to?

Answer (score 0):

see this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SGy4R/6/)**

**EDIT**

you can remove `#container width` and add `#container padding-right:20px;`

```
.box{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    margin-left:20px;;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    color:white;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:boh;
}
#container{        
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

Comment: Your Fiddle hasn't removed the margin?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".clearfix").prev().css("float","right").css("margin","0px");
```

AND

```
$($($(".clearfix").nextAll())[3]).css("float","right").css("margin","0px");
```

Will do what you need.

Comment: This will remove the `margin-left` from the last block.

Comment: OP wants margin right 0 so... I also tested it localy and it works as OP wants. At least from what i understood

Comment: And what about when there are two or three boxes per row as OP stated?

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margins on the container and get rid of your clearfix divs:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/dwbHi

```
#container {
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container .box {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `float`ing the `.box`es, you can use `display: inline-block` and 
add `text-align: justify` to `#container`.

But it still wouldn't work as expected yet, so you take the extra `div` you used for clearfix and relegate it to the bottom of the `#container` in the markup.

Then you change the name of the class from `.clearfix` to something like `.spacer`; 
the spacer class will have: `display: inline-block` and `width: 100%`.

You will also need to give `.box`es `vertical-align: top;` otherwise the horizontal alignment can break if `inline` elements like text exists in the boxes.

You'll notice now that the boxes are arranged with proper spacing in between and the first and last boxes in a line stick to the edges.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SGy4R/11/)

Markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>    
    <div class="box"></div>    
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box">the last box needs no margin right when full width and responsive</div>    
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box">the last box needs no margin right when full width and responsive</div>

    <div class='spacer'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
    }

#container {
    width: 480px;
    border:1px solid black;

    text-align: justify;
    }

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; 

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:red;

    margin-bottom:20px;
    color:white;
    }

.spacer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Here's an article which explains more about this method http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/.